# Determine whether $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T \mid x_1 = x_2 = x_3\}$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine whether $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T \mid x_1 = x_2 = x_3\}$ is a subspace

I know that I must show that it is closed under addition and multiplication, but I'm confused as to how I should approach doing that.

Comment: Just write down and unfold the definition of "closed under addition" and similarly for multiplication. There is almost nothing that needs to be done.

Comment: This is the span of $\{(1,1,1)\}$. If you know that the linear span of any nonempty set is a subspace, you are done.

Answer (score 3):

This is the set of all vectors of the form $(t,t,t)$. Note that $\lambda(t,t,t)=(\lambda t,\lambda t,\lambda t)$ and $(m,m,m)+(n,n,n)=(m+n,m+n,m+n)$ which is of the same form. Finally, note that the set is nonempty as it contains  $(0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\{u\mid \Phi(u)\}$ is the set of those $u$ elements, which satisfy a given property $\Phi$. In your case, it is the set of somethings of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$, such that $x_1=x_2=x_3$. Here $()^T$ means *transposition*, i.e. it is rather this column vector: $\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$, because in linear algebra one usually works with column vectors.

You have to prove that if you pick two *arbitrary* elements, and add them, it stays in the same set, and similarly for multiplication by an *arbitrary* scalar. Arbitrarity in this algebraic language means basically that you use *letters* instead of concrete numbers, hence will be generally true for all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$(0,0,0)\in W\implies W\neq\phi$

Whenever $a=(a_1,a_1,a_1)\in W$ and $b=(b_1,b_1,b_1)\in W$, then $\lambda a+\mu b=(\lambda a_1+\mu b_1,\lambda a_1+\mu b_1,\lambda a_1+\mu b_1)\in W$

Thus, $W$ is a subspace.